# jQuery Multi Select Option - Check if a option is selected or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a HTML Multi select box

```
<form action="form_action.php" method="Post">
<select name="cars[]" multiple id="select_id">
    <option value="all" id="option_id">All</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is check if option "All" is selected or not in jQuery.

What I have tried is

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#option_id')
                .click(
                    function()
                    {
                        if ($("#select_id option[value='all']").length == 0) { //value does not exist so add
                            //Do something if not selected
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //DO something if selected
                        }
                        //$("#select_id option:selected").removeAttr("selected");           //Remove
                        //$("#select_id option").attr('selected', 'selected');      //Add
                    }
                );
        });
    </script>
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please do as below code

```
$('#option_id').click(function(){
if ($("#select_id option[value=all]:selected").length > 0){
    alert('all is selected');
}
else{
    //DO something if not selected
}
//$("#select_id option:selected").removeAttr("selected");           //Remove
//$("#select_id option").attr('selected', 'selected');      //Add
});
```

You can check below fiddle

[Multi Select](http://jsfiddle.net/11vs42aq/1/)

Comment: @TheThinker: This is working for above question. If your question is different then Please post your separate question for that? and if your question is same then let me know what error you geting?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `:selected` selector for option to determine whether it is selected or not

```
if ($("#select_id option[value=all]:selected").length > 0){
   //all is selected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you're trying to detect whether it has been selected when you change the option in the `<select>` box, right?

Try this:

```
$("#select_id").change(function () {
  if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "all") {
    // all is selected
  } else {
    // all isn't selected
  }
});
```